# Access VB IIf and dlookup

Tags: ms-access, dlookup

I'm trying to change the below code to incorporate several selnames,167 & 789 both would use the same Query as below. I have tried several suggestions but no luck - any ideas?

Code:

```
IIf([selName]=167, DLookUp("[Desc]","[OptLQuery]","Index=selOptL"))
```

Comment: IIf(OR([selName]=167,[selName]=789),DLookUp("[Desc]","[OptLQuery]","Index=selOptL")) ought to work I think (but can't test)

Comment: Thank you for your response I tested but only 167 gets a result. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that in VBA or in a Query ? Why don't you use a `JOIN` ?

Comment: IIF([SelName] In (167,789),...?

Comment: Hi ive tried the above but its not returning any results for option L re 167 or 789. Option L has different results for both selnames which when dlookup should populate in a description box.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
IIf([selName]=167 OR [selName]=789, DLookUp("[Desc]","[OptLQuery]","Index=selOptL"))
```

Comment: Hi ive tried the above but its not returning any results for option L re 167 or 789. Option L has different results for both selnames which when dlookup should populate in a description box.

Comment: @Shevy Can you add screenshot of UI so that its more clear